# Ignore Text in HTML::TreeBuilder Output Perl

Tags: perl, html-parsing, perl-module

I need to ignore or remove all text in between all HTML elements so I can generate a blank template from a given web page.

I am parsing using the perl module HTML::TreeBuilder and HTML::Element.

I have tried the ignore_text method noted in the documentation but that doesn't provide correct results.

I have also tried using DOMXpath with PHP to do the same thing and results seemed too cumbersome to manage. Regex's might work but are a last resort to me.

This is part of my current code, very basic. Bottom is just output to file. All code is functional I just need formatting to work so I can generate template files.

`my $url= "http://www.example.com";`

```
my $page = get($url) or die $!;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($page);

$tree->parse_file($page);

$tree->ignore_text;
$tree->elementify;

open OUTPUT, "+>".$body;
my $output = $tree->as_HTML;
print OUTPUT $output;
close OUTPUT;
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: I found the problem - the ignore text only works when you parse from a physical file. I had to save the page as a temp file to parse then output the way I wanted with no text then I just did unlink($tmp) at the bottom to delete the file. My script has since grown much more complicated with reading and writing to database and each time I need to create this temp file which is kind of annoying...

Thanks for the reply below!

Comment: Instead of proposing an edit to provide the solution, either delete the question or post your solution as an answer (which you can then accept) so people can benefit from it in the future. You might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn more about how SO works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.

It looks like you need to set `ignore_text` with a true value. `$tree->ignore_text(1)` and then make sure its set before calling `parse_file`.

Sorry this is a bit long but i hope it helps.

Here is quick pass at the new code, hard to test without example page:

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;

$tree->ignore_text(1);
$tree->elementify;
$tree->parse_file( $page );
```

Here is my quick test script using a local file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $page = 'test.html';
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();

$tree->ignore_text(1);
$tree->parse_file($page);
$tree->elementify;

print $tree->as_HTML;
```

Input `test.html`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>title text</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>paragraph text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title></head><body><h1></h1><p></body></html>
```

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use HTML::Parser for this task. It is maybe a little bit more code, but should not to complicated.